# facebook connects to both http and https on http site

Tags: facebook

Does anybody know why facebook connects to both https and http.
Urls are:
    https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php
    http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php
They have the same content, so i don't see any reason why it should get them both?
Google page speeds punishes me for loading the same content twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's so that anyone using the service can load the data from SSL/nonSSL, as SSL content should never reference nonSSL content.

Comment: You could always try load it via ajax after the pageload is complete to speed up your google page speeds?

Comment: I am already loading it async, after pageload. I would think facebook would be so smart to only load the one it needed.

Comment: @MichielThalen, you'd think ;)